what is the average number of revisions when drafting a patent application with a lawyer?
If one is working with a lawyer specifically to draft a software method patent provisional application, what is the expected number revisions, or back and forth, or drafts between the lawyer and the inventor?
I am up to the 4th revision with my lawyer, where each revision includes typos that I found and new material.

Typos are not good in a draft  (I make a lot on this site) in a draft but should be 100% eliminated from the final revision.

This can vary widely depending on the complexity of the invention, the lawyer and your ability to catch errors. By four drafts you should be nearly done I would hope.
Considering how many questions you are asking here I am surmising that you are questioning your attorney on everything. While this is your right as the client, it’s bound to slow things down.
